# How to Detect Key press from Keyboard without textField?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

i used `SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.show");` to display keyboard without textField and it is working but i can't detect key pressed on the keyboard how can i do that?

i am tring to make virtual touchpad and keyboard like the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import '../../shared/cubit/cubit.dart';

class VirtualTouchpadAndKeyboard extends StatelessWidget {
  VirtualTouchpadAndKeyboard({super.key});
  
  final FocusNode _keyboardFocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppCubit cubit = AppCubit.get(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.keyboard_backspace,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Text("Test",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // Touchpad Section
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Virtual Touchpad',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5.0,
            ),
            // Keyboard Section
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black12,
                child: Center(
                  child:Visibility(
                    visible: true,
                    child: TextField(
                      focusNode: _keyboardFocusNode,
                      maxLines: null,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black54),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "What's in your mind",
                        fillColor: Colors.white54,
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.cyanAccent),
                        ),
                        prefix: Icon(Icons.keyboard_alt_outlined),
                        prefixIconColor: Colors.black12,
                      ),
                      onChanged: (val){
                        print(val);
                      }
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
              ),
            )],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        onPressed: () {
          // Request focus on the hidden text field
          SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.show");
          
          
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.keyboard, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```